# How to pass a variable with decimal places in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am having real difficulty with this and every answer I have seen doesnt seem to work. I have been able to pass a value such as 1.44 as 1.00 but the two decimal values are being lost. I have a number of values passed from a from which i then want to submit to an api via a call. The code is below:

```
IncomeWagesWeekly = params[:WagesWeekly].to_i
```

How do i ensure that when this is passed the two decimal places are present. Thanks for any help.

Comment: So, do you want `1.44` or `1.00`? FYI, math-wise, `1.00` is the same as `1.0` which, basically, is the same as `1`.

Comment: What would you want to happen with 1.55? Should it become 2.00?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have in Ruby language such thing as fixed digits after decimal point.

`1` is the same as `1.00` as it was rightfully mentioned before in comment (almost the same).

If you don't check it's type like that:

```
1.is_a? Integer # => true
1.is_a? Float # => false
```

it is all the same.

Just use `1.44.to_i`.

If by some reason you want to have an instance of `Float` instead use `to_f` method. To crop number explicitly you should use `round`, or `ceil`, or `floor` method:

```
1.44.round.to_f # => 1.0
1.55.round.to_f # => 2.0

1.44.ceil.to_f # => 2.0
1.55.ceil.to_f # => 2.0

1.44.floor.to_f # => 1.0
1.55.floor.to_f # => 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe don't try to make in integer and use `to_f` instead. Also consider any `sprintf( "%0.02f", your_number)`, but it returns string.

Comment: I just tried out sprintf and it seemed to be okay which is strange if it is a string as the API and database should not accept anything but an integer for these fields but there doesnt seem to be a problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3385136 *"API and database should not accept anything but an integer"* - neither 1.44 nor 1.00 look like integers. Could you clarify your requirements, please?

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems that you want to do fixed-point arithmetic here. So, using a floating point number is not the right choice, since floating point calculations can produce mathematically incorrect results.

A solution for this would be either to stick with Integers (as has been suggested already), or to use the data type [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html), which is defined in the Ruby standard library, and in particular its methods `fix`, `frac` and `to_digits`.

Now to your database: You didn't say what database you are using, and how you pass the values to it, but in general, it is a bad idea to store a non-integer value into a database-field which is supposed to accept integers. As you observed, the fractional part was dropped. Correct behaviour.

You could redefine your database schema, or you can convert your decimal value by yourself into something which matches the field definition in the database. Which way to go, depends on what you want to actually *do* with this value afterwards. For instance, if you just want to display it, but not perform any calculations, you could use a string. Or, if you know that the number of fractional digits don't exceed a certain limit, you could define a suitable numeric format for the database column - etc.